# Need help ATtiny85 not working as standalone

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny, electronics, attiny85

I have ATTiny85 that I want to drive a servo. Burned bootloader to the ATTiny85 and I am using HW-260 development board to program and to test the code. While the ATTiny85 works perfectly on the HW-260 development board, I cant get it to work as a standalone on a breadboard when testing with the servo by using the Adafruit_SoftServo library and with the blink example. Tried adding 4.7kOhm pull-up resistor to PB5 to prevent the ATTiny85 from resetting but I get the same result. Tried powering the standalone layout with 3V coin cell, USB 5V, powerbank 5V and nothing. This is the servo code I am using:

```
Adafruit_SoftServo myservo;
int pos = 0;
void setup() {
  myservo.attach(PB0);
}
void loop() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) {
    myservo.write(pos);
    myservo.refresh();
    delay(15);
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
    myservo.write(pos);
    myservo.refresh();
    delay(15);
  }
}
```

The blink code I am using is from the examples, I just change the output pin as PB1. If I connect the PB5 briefly to ground, I get the servo to turn a bit in random direction. Measured and the breadboard is not the problem, everything seems to be connected correctly.

This is the bootloader I used https://github.com/ashishchoudhary9998/ATtiny85-Boot-loader

**Edit:**
This is the schematic of the HW-260 board
[image]

This is my layout
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. You might also want to read "[ask]" and some of the [help]. -- If the same program works on the development board, but not on your board, you need to find out the differences. Please [edit] your question and add schematics (or at least relevant parts of them)for both.

Comment: thanks @thebusybee I edited the question and added the schematics.

Comment: Concerning the Blinky example, working on the HW-260, but not on your board, there is only just one difference: PB3 is pulled up by 1k5. Would you mind to add this to your board, and retry, please? And what do you see with Blinky on your board, a completely off LED, a completely on LED, or something in-between? BTW, do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: @thebusybee sure, i will try pulling PB3 up right away and i will let you know what will be the result. i dont have an oscilloscope :(
thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @thebusybee it works :) adding a pull-up resistor to PB3 fixes the issue and the code is working perfectly. thanks allot. btw the current firmware (bootloader) has some kind of delay, i measured like 5-6 seconds delay before the code starts working. can you please add your comment as an answer so i can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the schematics, a difference can be spotted:

PB3 needs a pull-up, on the development board it has 1,5 kΩ. This resistor is part of the [USB standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_(Communications)#Line_transition_state) and signals "low speed device". Presumably (because the source of it is not provided) the bootloader needs this to start at all, too.

The delay mentioned in a comment is typical for ATtiny85 development. Because of the low number of pins, the bootloader starts and waits for some seconds for a PC to connect. If no connection is established, the user program is started. It can then use all pins for its own purposes.